# Where can we get all the list of fontfamily we can use without importing it externally in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

What are all default font families supported by flutter? I don't want it to download manually and use it by manually adding `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

In the recent release of flutter `1.12` they have added hundreds of new font family to the flutter framework

> We Also have a new Google Fonts package that provides direct access to almost 1,000 open sourced font families, putting beautiful typography within reach in just a line of code.

you can find how to use guide and list fo fonts here https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts